# HoldForm behaviour for product of a Graph and an expression

Tags: list-manipulation, hold

Suppose I have a list of pairs each containing an expression and an associated `Graph` object:

```
list={{G^4/48,Graph[List[1,2],List[UndirectedEdge[1,2],UndirectedEdge[1,2],UndirectedEdge[1,2],UndirectedEdge[1,2]],List[Rule[EdgeStyle,List[Thickness[Large]]],Rule[FormatType,TraditionalForm]]]},{G^4/16,Graph[List[1,2],List[UndirectedEdge[1,1],UndirectedEdge[1,2],UndirectedEdge[1,2],UndirectedEdge[2,2]],List[Rule[EdgeStyle,List[Thickness[Large]]],Rule[FormatType,TraditionalForm]]]}}
```

Now, I want to obtain a product of the each pair. I tried:

```
Times @@@ list
```

But, the problem is that of formatting, the expression gets completely mixed with the `Graph` object:

[image]

I want simple product without any further mixing:

[image]

How to achieve this? I tried playing around with `HoldForm` and `Print`, but I failed to get them to work.

Comment: Wrap the factor in `HoldForm`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Cool! It worked

Comment: If it is just for displaying purposes then `Row@*Reverse /@ list` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on @Szabolcs' neat comment:

```
With[{x = #[[1]], y = #[[2]]}, HoldForm[x] y] & /@ list
```

The result looks thus looks like:

[image: Output]